# Filtro de busca não específico

Tags: php, mysql, filtro

Tenho uma página com um filtro de busca com as opções de "serviço", "estado" e "cidade" e um botão submit que redireciona pra página onde vai aparecer uma tabela com os cadastros já filtrados.

Porém atualmente o filtro só funciona se as três opções forem preenchidas limitando o usuário a procurar um serviço só se procurar junto o estado e a cidade, sendo que o objetivo é que ele não seja obrigado a preencher as três opções do filtro, podendo ver todos os serviços da cidade, por exemplo.

Essa é a página com o filtro:

```
<?php require_once("_topo.php"); ?>

<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_qualquer");
    //Verificar se está sendo passado na URL a página atual, senao é atribuido a pagina 
    $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;

    $result_serv = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE permicao = 'sim' ORDER BY servico";
    $resultado_serv = mysqli_query($link, $result_serv);
    $result_servN = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE permicao = 'sim' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $resultado_servN = mysqli_query($link, $result_servN);
    //Contar o total de serv
    $total_serv = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_serv);

    //Seta a quantidade de cursos por pagina
    $quantidade_pg = 10;

    //calcular o número de pagina necessárias para apresentar os cursos
    $num_pagina = ceil($total_serv/$quantidade_pg);

    //Calcular o inicio da visualizacao
    $incio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg;

    //Selecionar os cursos a serem apresentado na página
    $result_serv = "SELECT * FROM teste limit $incio, $quantidade_pg";
    $resultado_serv = mysqli_query($link, $result_serv);
    $total_serv = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_serv);

?>

<?php 
    require 'conexao.php';
    $queryServicos = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT DISTINCT servico FROM teste ORDER BY servico"); 
    $id           = $_POST["id"];
    $serv       = $_POST["servico"];

?>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <form action="teste-busca.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon">Serviço:</i></span>
                          <select name="servico" id="servico" class="form-control">
                            <option>Selecione...</option>
                            <!-- PEGA OS SERVIÇOS DO BANCO DE DADOS E COLOCA NO OPTION -->
                                <?php while($serv = mysqli_fetch_array($queryServicos)) { ?> 
                                <option value="<?php echo $serv['servico']; ?>"><?php echo $serv['servico']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                             -->
                          </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">Estado:</i></span>
                      <select name="estado" id="estados" class="form-control">
                      </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">Cidade:</i></span>
                      <select name="cidade" id="cidades" class="form-control">
                        <option value="none">Selecione um estado</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-1">Buscar</button>
                </div>
                </form>

            <!-- Aqui a tabela é criada -->
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Essa é a página redirecionada pelo filtro de busca:

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_qualquer");
    //Verificar se está sendo passado na URL a página atual, senao é atribuido a pagina 
    $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;

    $result_serv = "SELECT * FROM teste";
    $resultado_serv = mysqli_query($link, $result_serv);
    //Contar o total de serv
    $total_serv = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_serv);

    //Seta a quantidade de cursos por pagina
    $quantidade_pg = 10;

    //calcular o número de pagina necessárias para apresentar os cursos
    $num_pagina = ceil($total_serv/$quantidade_pg);

    //Calcular o inicio da visualizacao
    $incio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg;

    //Selecionar os cursos a serem apresentado na página
    $result_serv = "SELECT * FROM teste limit $incio, $quantidade_pg";
    $resultado_serv = mysqli_query($link, $result_serv);
    $total_serv = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_serv);

?>
<?php 
    require 'conexao.php';
?>

<!-- - - - - - Isso aqui é o filtro - - - - - - - - - -->
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    $lnk = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysqli_error()) or die ('Nao foi possível conectar ao MySql: ' . mysqli_error($lnk));
    mysqli_select_db($lnk,'db_qualquer') or die ('Nao foi possível ao banco de dados selecionado no MySql: ' . mysqli_error($lnk));
    //require("conexao.php")

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM teste ORDER BY servico, estado, cidade ASC';
    $servico = $_POST['servico'];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];

    if(!is_null($servico) && !empty($servico)) 
        $sqli = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE servico LIKE '%".$servico."%' AND estado LIKE '%".$estado."%' AND cidade LIKE '%".$cidade."%'";

    $qry = mysqli_query($lnk, $sqli) or die(mysqli_error($lnk));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
    $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado
    //$fields[] = array();
    if($num_fields > 0) {
        for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
            $fields[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($qry,$i)->name;
        }
    } 
?> 

<!-- - - - - - Tabela com as buscas- - - - - - -->
<table class="table table-bordered"> <tr>
<tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Serviço</th>
    <th class="no-responsive">Cidade</th>
    <th>Visualizar</th>
</tr>
<?php
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }
    ?>
<tr>
        <td><?=$row['nome'];?></td>
        <td><?=$row['servico'];?></td>
        <td class="no-responsive"><?=$row['cidade'];?></td>
        <td><a href="visualiza.php?id=<?=$row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-primary">Visualizar</a></td>
</tr>
        <?php    }?>
</table>

<?php

$table .= '<tbody>';
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }
}
?>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

> OBS: No caso o usuário poderia escolher ou ver todos os registros com
>   aquele serviço ou ver todos os registros com aquele registro e estado
>   e cidade, uma vez que uma vez preenchido meu estado, ele
>   automaticamente já preenche a cidade baseado num json que eu uso. :/

Já tentei trocar o AND pelo OR mas não funciona se você escolher só dois dos três filtros por exemplo.
É possível fazer com que não precise preencher todas as opções usando o filtro que eu já tenho?

Aqui tentei usar o filtro de uma das respostas, mas deu que a página não estava funcionando:

```
<?
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    $lnk = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysqli_error()) or die ('Nao foi possível conectar ao MySql: ' . mysqli_error($lnk));
    mysqli_select_db($lnk,'db_qualquer') or die ('Nao foi possível ao banco de dados selecionado no MySql: ' . mysqli_error($lnk));



    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM teste ORDER BY servico, estado, cidade ASC';
    $servico = isset($_POST['servico']) ? $_POST['servico'] : null;
    $estado = isset($_POST['estado']) ? $_POST['estado'] : null;
    $cidade = isset($_POST['cidade']) ? $_POST['cidade'] : null;
    $arrParams = [];

    $sqli = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE ";
    if(!is_null($servico) && !empty($servico)){
        $arrParams[] = [
            'filter' => 'servico',
            'value' => $servico
        ];
    }
    if (!is_null($estado) && !empty($estado)) {
        $arrParams[] = [
            'filter' => 'estado',
            'value' => $estado
        ];
    }
    if (!is_null($cidade) && !empty($cidade)) {
        $arrParams[] = [
            'filter' => 'cidade',
            'value' => $cidade
        ];
    }
    $cont = 1;
    $total = count($arrParams);
    foreach($arrParams as $param){

        $sqli .= $param['filter'] . " LIKE '%".$param['value']."%'";
        if ($total > 1 && $cont != $total) {
            $sqli.= "AND ";
        }
        $cont ++;
    }
    $qry = mysqli_query($lnk, $sqli) or die(mysqli_error($lnk));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
    $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado
    //$fields[] = array();
    if($num_fields > 0) {
        for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
            $fields[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($qry,$i)->name;
        }
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver dessa maneira, quebrando o sql em partes:

```
$servico = isset($_POST['servico']) ? $_POST['servico'] : null;
$estado = isset($_POST['estado']) ? $_POST['estado'] : null;
$cidade = isset($_POST['cidade']) ? $_POST['cidade'] : null;
$arrParams = [];

$sqli = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE ";
if(!is_null($servico) && !empty($servico)){
    $arrParams[] = [
        'filter' => 'servico',
        'value' => $servico
    ];
}
if (!is_null($estado) && !empty($estado)) {
    $arrParams[] = [
        'filter' => 'estado',
        'value' => $estado
    ];
}
if (!is_null($cidade) && !empty($cidade)) {
    $arrParams[] = [
        'filter' => 'cidade',
        'value' => $cidade
    ];
}
$cont = 1;
$total = count($arrParams);
foreach($arrParams as $param){

    $sqli .= $param['filter'] . " LIKE '%".$param['value']."%'";
    if ($total > 1 && $cont != $total) {
        $sqli.= "AND ";
    }
    $cont ++;
}
$qry = mysqli_query($lnk, $sqli) or die(mysqli_error($lnk));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
$num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado
//$fields[] = array();
if($num_fields > 0) {
    for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
        $fields[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($qry,$i)->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: É uma boa sugestão, mas acaba funcionando na mesma maneira, só com todos os filtros preenchidos. :/

Comment: Você quer procurar só por cidade e estado também? serviço não é obrigatório?

Comment: Editei para todos serem independentes

Comment: Eu tentei usar esse filtro (que tá muito bem estruturadinho por sinal) e deu que a página não está funcionando. Vou editar minha pergunta pra mostrar como eu coloquei.

Comment: Mariana, tente imprimir o resultado final da variável antes de ela ser executada e veja se ela está sendo montada de maneira correta. e se possível informe o erro, aqui funcionou

Answer (score 1):

Mariana veja se isto te ajuda:

```
$where = '';
$whereFiltro = array();
$filtroConsulta = '';

if(!is_null($servico) && !empty($servico))
{
   $whereFiltro[] = "servico LIKE '%{$servico}%'";
}

if(!is_null($estado) && !empty($estado))
{
   $whereFiltro[] = "estado LIKE '%{$estado}%'";
}

if(!is_null($cidade) && !empty($cidade))
{
  $whereFiltro[] = "cidade LIKE '%{$cidade}%'";
}

//quebra o array para string e coloca o AND
if (count($whereFiltro) > 0)
{
   $where = implode("\n AND ", $whereFiltro);
}

if(strlen($where) > 0)
{
   $filtroConsulta = "WHERE " . $where;
} 

$sqli = "SELECT * FROM teste {$filtroConsulta}";
```

[implode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php)

[strlen](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php)